# Best way to use MySQL clause "Use index('index_name')" using ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to use the SQL clause "Use index('index_name')" to an ActiveRecord query, does anyone knows a good way to do it with Activerecord
I wanted to avoid adding string directly to the query.

Comment: http://m.onkey.org/use-index-with-active-record-finders

Comment: Thanks , this was helpfull , I end up using 'from' method from ActiveRecord - Arel  EX: `from='pages Use index(some_index); 'Page.from(from).where(id: 1)`

Comment: see also: https://gist.github.com/glv/703997

Answer (score 3):

I use this in my models:

```
def self.use_index(index)
  from("#{self.table_name} USE INDEX(#{index})")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow up, I've just implemented a solution based on James' above but used a scope instead:

```
  scope :force_index, -> (index) {
    from("#{table_name} FORCE INDEX(#{index})")
  }
```